# Are electrostatic forces enough to trap charged particles?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

Imagine we have a double walled sphere from an insulating material.(So like an outer shere with smaller sphere inside it)

If we insert a fully ionized gas inside the space of the double wall could we theoretically "trap" inside the sphere protons for example?

Will the electrostatic forces the electrons feel from the gas when near the wall of the sphere be enough to stop them or they need a classic electric or magnetic field to be contained?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Electrostatic forces in vacuum are *not* enough to trap a charged particle. In your example, if you apply a voltage to one or both of the spheres, the particles will be attracted to the lowest potential which is one of the sphere's surface and will not be trapped in space.

To trap a charged particle in space, electrostatic forces are insufficient, you must have **at least one of the following**

1. Net charge density, $\rho(r) \neq 0$, at the particle position,
2. Magnetic fields
3. Time-varying electromagnetic forces.

These conditions comes from [Earnshaw's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earnshaw%27s_theorem).

Scenario **(1)** tends to not be very useful in general because the charged particle will tend to be neutralized in the presence of oppositely charged particles (via e.g. chemical bond formation). One exception is if you're trapping electrons, rather than ions.

Scenario **(2)** is used in [Penning traps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penning_trap). These are used for trapping anti-particles. The disadvantage is the cyclotron motion

While scenario **(3)** is used for [Paul traps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_trap). These have the advantage of being more compact than Penning traps, but carry the downside of micromotion heating.

Edit: To explain the comment by user @Rococo note that the polarization of an insulator by a moving charge *is* time-dependent so it nominally evades Earnshaw's theorem. However, all insulators have a loss term, and *cannot* have a gain term, (i.e. a charged particle will always tend to lose energy to an insulator until it reaches the same temperature) and so this method cannot really be used for trapping charged particles. The only stable state in such a context would be when the particle has near zero energy, at which point Earnshaw's theorem applies and the particle will likely collide with the insulator.

That said, *maybe* if there was a very specific ion velocity and dielectric function, then you could trap a charged particle in a metastable fashion. Though as soon as the particle loses a bit of energy, the meta-trapping would fail.

Comment: I Fixed the link

Comment: I accidentally said electrons instead of protons but it doesn't change anything.Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Scenario (1) is part of how a charge-coupled device works.

Comment: @JohnDoty yes, I should specify I had in mind charged atoms (aka ions), but for electrons things are different.

Comment: This is correct but doesn't seem to me to address the main question of the text. Induced electric fields, which seem to be what the OP has in mind, are not static (despite the OP's use of that term) and as such are not subject to Earnshaw's theorem.

Comment: @Rococo, not sure I follow. Are you suggesting that the ions create a fluctuating field that self traps them? Unless the materials are driven like in an RF Paul trap, I don't see how the stabilized trapped particles can maintain that fluctuating field once they are trapped. Seems like there would have to be energy injection to keep that running, and then it would come under scenario 3

Comment: @KFGauss A moving charge, in the presence of an insulating dielectric, will result in a charge configuration that is not static but varies with the position of the inducing charge- no? So yes, I am suggesting that perhaps in principle one could imagine a self-induced field that leads a charge to be trapped, if not at a single point at least in a closed orbit. Maybe there are other considerations that forbid this, but it is not forbidden by Earnshaw's theorem (and it is not obvious to me that the energetic considerations that you suggest forbid it either).

Comment: @Rococo That's right, Earnshaw's theorem doesn't address that scenario. But the permittivity of any relevant material always includes a loss term by Kramers Kronig, so I don't see how you could trap anything with that method except in a driven system. The particle would lose energy at a rate of about $\textrm{Im} \epsilon^{-1}(\omega)$. In the driven case, I would argue you're more similar to scenario 3. Unless you're OK with a "temporary" trap?

Comment: Nit: Penning-traps _are_ temporary traps, because the magnetron-mode is unstable: Ff the trapped particle has any way to dissipate energy in that mode (for example, through collisions with background gas), the magnetron orbit will get bigger and bigger until the particle hits the trap walls.
But with a sufficiently good vacuum the trapping times can be made arbitrarily long. We have stored trapped antiprotons for years. We could also store protons for years, but protons are so cheap that it's not worth it.